# FastAPI function memory overusage problem

Tags: python, postgresql, fastapi

I have the following function in fastAPI. When I call it, my app's memory usage progressively increases to a level that exceeds the 1GB dedicated memory on Heroku platform. I use this function to read and write from a postgres table and call other server APIs.

program_records_model and ttmp_completion_model are sqlalchemy models based on the `declarative_base()`. The db is an instance of sqlalchemy Session. I used fastAPI `Depends()` to use this session.

The `get_user_info()` and `get_department_name()` are all functions that are used to call a server API.

I used gunicorn with 4 uvicorn workers to run my app on Heroku.

```
async def update_ttmp_completion(bearer_token, program_records_model, ttmp_completion_model, db: Session):
        records_to_add = []
        records_to_update = []
        add_count = 0
        update_count = 0
        errors = []
        # query the first table to get completion times and insert/update into the second table
        completed_learners = db.query(program_records_model.learner,
                                  program_records_model.enroll_at,
                                  program_records_model.finished_at,
program_records_model.online_seconds).filter(program_records_model.finished_at != None).distinct(program_records_model.learner).all() # gets the distinct learner_id for all of those who have completed any variation of program.
    
    for i, (learner_id, enrollment_time, completion_time, online_seconds) in enumerate(completed_learners):
        if learner_id:
            existing_learner = db.query(ttmp_completion_model).filter(ttmp_completion_model.user_id == learner_id).first()
            if existing_learner:
                # logger.debug(msg=f'Completed learner {learner_id} already exists and will be updated.')
                existing_learner.enrollment_time = enrollment_time
                existing_learner.completion_time = completion_time
                existing_learner.online_seconds = online_seconds
                records_to_update.append(vars(existing_learner)) # vars() turns SQLAlchemy object into python dictionary that can be used by .bulk_update_mappings() method later.
            else:
                # logger.debug(msg=f'Completed learner {learner_id} is new and will be added.')
                try:
                    learner_info = await get_user_info(bearer_token=bearer_token, user_id=learner_id, user_id_type='open_id') # if the learner does not exist we need to call API to get their information.
                    name = learner_info['en_name']
                    manager_id = learner_info['manager_id']
                    email = learner_info['email']
                    department_id = learner_info['department_id']
                    department_name = await get_dep_name(bearer_token=bearer_token, department_id=department_id)
                except Exception as e:
                    errors.append(e)
                    continue # will skip to the next iteration of the for loop.
                new_record = ttmp_completion_model(user_id=learner_id, name=name, email=email, department_id=department_id, department_name=department_name,
                                                    completion_time=completion_time, online_seconds=online_seconds, manager_id=manager_id, enrollment_time=enrollment_time)
                records_to_add.append(new_record)
        else:
            logger.error(msg='No learner id was provided for the completed learner!')
        if len(records_to_add) >= 50 or i == len(completed_learners) - 1: # we break the database updates to batches of n size so that a potential error does not hault the entire update process.
            try:
                if records_to_update:
                    db.bulk_update_mappings(ttmp_completion_model, records_to_update) # unlike bulk_save_objects(), this method takes dictionaries.
                    update_count += len(records_to_update)
                if records_to_add:
                    db.bulk_save_objects(records_to_add)
                    add_count += len(records_to_add)
                db.commit()
                logger.info(msg='50 or less new records were added.')
                records_to_add = []
                records_to_update = []
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(msg=f'Error occurred adding to db: {e}')
                db.rollback()

    return {'new_record_count': add_count, 'upate_count': update_count, 'error_count': len(errors)}
```

I call this function in a fastAPI route using await method but I have tried calling it directly as well and the issue remains.

Comment: Why do you meed 4 workers? If you're having memory issues, try going down to 1.

Comment: @M.O. I tried using 1 worker instead too and the memory usage for similar tasks remained pretty much the same.

Comment: Have you found the root cause and a solution? I am having the same issue with my API which uses  BackgroundTasks.